# How to maximize area bounded by thread and a fixed line?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Suppose we have a circle with a radius $R$ having a thread of length $L_0$ tied at diametrically opposite ends such that $2R < L_0 < \pi R$. What shape the thread must be in order to minimize the shaded area.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: This was initially a surface tension problem from my physics assignment.

Comment: An heuristic idea: because of the symmetry of the circle, I would expect the shape of the thread to be symmetric around the perpendicular to the diagonal that goes through the points where the thread is attached

Comment: Including that intial context in the body of your Question would significantly improve it.  Note that minimizing the shaded area is equivalent to *maximizing*... what area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the same as maximizing the surface area between the thread and the thread and the diameter, imposing that the thread stays below the half circle.

[image]

The solution to this problem is the arc circle: indeed we know that the circle has optimal area/perimeter ratio. Consider the circle of radius R' such that the circle arc between two points $A$, $B$ such that $AB = 2R$ is precisely $L_0$.

Assume that the arc circle is not the shape with optimal area/perimeter ratio, and call $\ell$ a better shape. Then the shape of the circle minus the arc, glued to $\ell$ would have the same perimeter as the circle, but a higher surface area, which implies a contradiction. [image: a]

Thus the circle arc is optimal without the constraint of being below the half-circle. Since it **is** under the half-circle, then it is the optimal solution in this setting as well.